# Set-AzureADUserLicense : Cannot bind parameter 'AssignedLicenses'

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am creating a custom script that will create a new AD user account and based on a input of 1,2,or 3, it will give the user a specific O365 license. In PS ISE help, there is this example which I am trying to utilize to assign the O365 license to the new user. However I get an error as specified in the title. The variable $email is specified above.

````
Connect-AzureAD
$licensetype = Read-host - Prompt 'Press 1 for EOP1, 2 for Business Basic, and 3 for Business Standard'
if ($licensetype -eq 1)
{
$LicensedUser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "user1@email.com"  
$User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $email  
$License = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense 
$License.SkuId = $LicensedUser.AssignedLicenses.SkuId 
$Licenses = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses 
$Licenses.AddLicenses = $License 
Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $Licenses
}
elseif ($licensetype -eq 2)
{ 
$LicensedUser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "user2@email.com"  
$User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $email  
$License = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense 
$License.SkuId = $LicensedUser.AssignedLicenses.SkuId 
$Licenses = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses 
$Licenses.AddLicenses = $License 
Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $Licenses 
}
else
{
$LicensedUser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "user3@email.com"  
$User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $email  
$License = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense 
$License.SkuId = $LicensedUser.AssignedLicenses.SkuId 
$Licenses = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses 
$Licenses.AddLicenses = $License 
Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $Licenses
}

Set-AzureADUserLicense : Cannot bind parameter 'AssignedLicenses'. Cannot convert the
"45a2423b-e884-448d-a831-d9e139c52d2f" value of type "System.String" to type
"Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses".
At D:\new-user.ps1:38 char:59
+ ... bjectId $email -AssignedLicenses 45a2423b-e884-448d-a831-d9e139c52d2f
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzureADUserLicense], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.SetUserLicenses```
````

Comment: Why not just use `$Licenses = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses`. Then `$Licenses.AddLicenses = $LicensedUser.AssignedLicenses`. Creating `$License` seems wasteful. Your error is happening because `$LicensedUser.AssignedLicenses.SkuId ` is an array. When you try to store that array into a single `.skuid` property, the elements are joined together to make a single string.

Comment: @AdminOfThings This should be correct. Do you mind moving your comment to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do the following to simplify your code:

```
Connect-AzureAD
# Stores string value 1,2, or 3
$licensetype = Read-host - Prompt 'Press 1 for EOP1, 2 for Business Basic, and 3 for Business Standard'
# hash table with string keys 1,2,3
# Expected usage: $emails['1'] for first email address
$emails = @{ '1' = 'user1@email.com'
             '2' = 'user2@email.com'
             '3' = 'user3@email.com'
}
# Only want to add licenses when user enters 1,2, or 3
if ($licensetype -in 1,2,3)
{
    $LicensedUser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $emails[$licensetype]
    $User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $email  
    $Licenses = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses 
    $Licenses.AddLicenses = $LicensedUser.AssignedLicenses
    Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $Licenses
}
```

---

In your attempt, `$LicensedUser.AssignedLicenses.SkuId` returns a collection of strings. This is because the `.AssignedLicenses` is a list of `Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense` objects. When you attempt to set that collection to a single string property `$License.SkuId`, the collection is converted to a string. That stringification joins the strings using the system's `$OFS` value (space by default). You would need to loop over each `$LicensedUser.AssignedLicenses.SkuId` value and create a new `Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense` object for each one.

Comment: Looks like it worked. I don't have any available licenses at the moment. But the only error I saw was that no licenses available. Thanks!